# DecodeURIComponent is not supporting for %uXXXX encoded component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encodeuricomponent, decodeuricomponent

#### DecodeURIComponent is not supporting for few encoded component

I am sending JD with bulletin format in my json , in restapi . So I am encoding the jd and sending. this works properly without any issues.But when I am trying to decode the encoded JD , I am getting error as URI malformed

```
var jd = "Where are bullets most often used?

 - Technical writing
 - Reference works
 - Notes
 - Presentations";


var json ={
"job":encodeURIComponent(escape(jd));

}
```

Decoding :

```
var jd = decodeURIComponent(jd);
```

thi is my encoded jd I am getting from response.

```
Where%20are%20bullets%20most%20often%20used%3F%0A%uF0B7Technical%20writing%0A%uF0B7Sub%20bullet%0A%uF0B7Reference%20works%0A%uF0B7Notes%0A%uF0B7Presentations%0A%uF0B7Lists%0AAn%20alternative%20method%20is%20to%20use%20a%u807Dnumbered%20list%3A%0A1.Technical%20writing%0A2.Reference%20works%0A3.Notes%0A4.Presentations%0A5.Lists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to `unescape` it first

```
var jd = decodeURIComponent(unescape(json.job));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid the use of `escape()`.

### From the Docs:

> ## escape()
>
> The `escape()` function computes a new string in which certain characters have been replaced by a hexadecimal escape sequence.
>
> #### Description
>
> The escape function is a property of the global object. Special characters are encoded with the exception of: `@*_+-./`
>
> The hexadecimal form for characters, whose code unit value is `0xFF` or less, is a two-digit escape sequence: `%xx`. For characters with a greater code unit, the four-digit format `%uxxxx` is used.
>
> ## Deprecated. Not for use in new websites.
>
> [— MDN JavaScript Reference - escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

### From Wikipedia:

> There exists a non-standard encoding for Unicode characters: `%uxxxx`, where `xxxx` is a UTF-16 code unit represented as four hexadecimal digits. This behavior is not specified by any RFC and has been [rejected](http://www.w3.org/International/iri-edit/draft-duerst-iri.html) by the W3C. The third edition of ECMA-262 still includes an `escape` function that uses this syntax, along with `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` functions, which apply UTF-8 encoding to a string, then percent-escape the resulting bytes.
>
> [— Wikipedia - Percent encoding - Non-standard implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations)

Comment: so what is the solution to handle ?

Comment: Don't use `escape`. `encodeURIComponent` is all you need.

Comment: encodeURIComponent throws an invalid URI for special characters.